# play 2.3.3 bonecp exception after upgrade

Tags: playframework-2.0, bonecp

I upgraded a java play 2.2 application to 2.3.3.  The database backend is MySql accessed through ebean.   At run time, it throws the following exception when I make an initial request.    I tried manually adding guava 17.0 and bonecp 0.8.0 as references in the project, did not make a difference.    Not sure why the bonecp is showing 0.7.1 in the stack trace with 0.8 in the library references in the build.sbt.

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource]
at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:170) ~[play_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.<init>(BoneCPDataSource.java:64) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.createDataSource(DB.scala:295) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.setupDatasources(DB.scala:411) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.<init>(DB.scala:418) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.play$api$db$BoneCPPlugin$$dbApi$lzycompute(DB.scala:211) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
```

Comment: Interesting, you might want to report this to the Play developers directly.

Comment: Try `show full-classpath` in SBT to check references to BoneCP